General solution for $x^{\prime} = x \cdot f(t,x)$ where $f \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$
I have that ODE:

$$x^{\prime} = x \cdot f(t,x)$$

here:
$$x^{\prime} = \frac{dx}{dt}$$
and $f$ is continuous in all $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
and the question is to prove that if $x(t) \not \equiv 0$ then $x(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$.
My attempt:
If we have that $x(t_{0}) \neq 0$ for some $t_0$ then there is a neighborhood of $t_0$ where $x(t)\neq0$ for all $t$ in that neigborhood so we can devide by $x$ and get $$\frac{x^{\prime}}{x} = f(t,x)$$
Here I'm not sure I can do integral w.r.t $t$ and say that $x(t) = ce^{\int_{t_0}^{t}f(s,x)ds}$.
I'll be glad for some help, thank you in advance.

Seems legit to me. You can conclude by noticing that $c = x(t_0) \neq 0$ and the exponential is a positive function.

Yeah that's what I wanted to say if that way is legit, thank you.

However, this doesn't allows you to find $x$...

You absolutely right, the question also doesn't require that, maybe the title I've chosen is a little bit misleading.

Take a solution $x:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $I = (t_0-\delta, t_0+\delta)$ for $\delta > 0$ that fulfils $x(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, let $\varepsilon \in (0, \delta)$. We observe for $t \in [t_0, t_0 + \varepsilon] =:J $:
$$
\lvert x(t) \rvert = \left \lvert \int_{t_0}^t \lvert x(s) \rvert \lvert f(s, x(s)) \rvert \mathrm{d}s\right \rvert \leq \max_{s \in J} \lvert f(s, x(s)) \rvert \int_{t_0}^t \lvert x(s) \rvert~\mathrm{d}s
$$
Thus, by Gronwall's Lemma $\lvert x(t) \rvert = 0$ for all $t\in [t_0, t_0+\varepsilon]$. By time inversion and by $\varepsilon$ being abritrary we can conclude that $\lvert x(t) \rvert = 0$ on $I$.
So it holds that if $x(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0$, we get that the solution is necessarily zero everywhere. This implies the property that you are looking for.
